# Combining data from two tables in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, join

I have two models, one belongs to the other. They look like this:

```
class LittleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :little_class_sessions
end
```

and

```
class LittleClassSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :little_class
end
```

`LittleClassSession` has a column called `little_class_id`. I want to get all `LittleClassSession` but also have the associated `LittleClass` returned to me in the same hash.

Is there some way to do this that's built into Rails? Or is there a clean way to do this?

And is this something that I build into the `LittleClass` or `LittleClassSession` model with `scope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query ActiveRecord you will get an array of ActiveRecord:Relation. It is a specific entity which starts your query. You can of course join dependent tables (as in your example with one-to-many relation). But you will still need to go over those dependent relations to build whatever object you need.

Here is a sketch of what I mean (assume we search for all little class sessions with specific little class id):

```
class_sessions = LittleClassSession.includes(:little_class).where(:little_classes => {:id => 1})

class_sessions.each do |relation| 
   test_hash = relation.attributes.merge!({:little_class => relation.little_class.attributes}); 
   puts test_hash 
end
```

test_hash will include all the attributes of the little class session as well as attributes of the little class under corresponding key.